# Redireccionamiento luego del hacer PUT a la api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola estoy creando una aplicacion por React, la cual tiene un CRUD a traves de diversas llamadas a la Api por los fetch. cuando quiero actualizar el post por medio de la funcion "update" que esta contenida en un archivo de stores y actions no me permite redirigirme a una url deseada despues de haber guardado y actualizado el post a la api por medio de PUT, es recomendable hacer un callback para el redireccionamiento luego de tantos segundos?. Adjunto mi codigo:

**boton**

```
    <button
    type="submit"
    className="btn btn-primary"
    onClick={e => {
    actions.update(e, dato.id);
    }}>
    Actualizar
    </button>
```

**Codigo de la funcion que ehecuta el PUT a la api**

```
update: (e, id) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const store = getStore();

            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/" + id + "/", {
                method: "PUT",
                body: JSON.stringify(store.updatedInfo),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
                }
            })
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log("status edit articulo ", resp.status);
                    setStore({
                        redirect: true
                    });
                    if (store.redirect === true) {
                        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
                    }

                    return resp.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("dato a editar", data);
                });
        },
```

Comment: La redirección es a nivel de la petición o a nivel de aplicación?

Comment: @nauseantparrot como lo puse alli, hice la redireccion luego de recibir la respuesta del servidor. (eso es a nivel de la peticion?), sorry metiendome hace pocos meses en el mundo.
Estaba pensando en ponerle un redirect tipico de JS pero siento que qebraria un poco la dinamica de react ya que este refrescaria la pagina.

Comment: Es a nivel de aplicación, a nivel de petición sería más una redirección por HTTP status code o cambiando el location; revisando tu código, pienso que tienes algunos inconvenientes, primero es necesario que analices si tú función setStore es asíncrona, en ese muy probablemente cuando evalúes el store.redirect este aún no haya cambiado, por otro lado el return que haces con el componente Redirect no está haciendo nada, ya que no cuentas con algo que lo reciba, podrías mostrar tu código de una forma más global para poder ayudarte?

Comment: @nauseantparrot, gracias por tu aclaracion, si de hecho estuve haciendo las pruebas para que ese estado en particular me cambie a True y efectivamente me genera el cambio de estado justo cuando recibe el objeto del servidor, pero este no redirecciona. estaba intentando hacer el cambio desde el mismo componente para ver si me podria salir

Comment: Estás usando react-router-dom? Podrías mostrar el código de una forma más global de forma que se muestre tú componente

Comment: @nauseantparrot solucionado amigo, gracias por tus datos efectivamente..estaba haciendo el setStore dentro de una de las respuestas del .then(). por lo cual saque hacia dentro de la funcion padre (la que el evento llamo) el setStore pasandolo a true y solo a traves de los consumidores hice un condicional que redireccione :D ! gracias!!! ahora me faltaria pasarle un callback asi no hace la redireccion tan rapido :D

Comment: Es bueno haber sido de ayuda amigo